# Does my computer / router / modem have an SPI bus?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

We are starting to do embedded programming. The single board computer that I am programming has a WiFi module that can communicate with a Serial Peripheral Interface Bus. That's all good. I know what this means: we can send bits, one at a time, *in sequence*, from one place to another. My question is:

- Does my computer, router, or modem have an SPI Bus?
- How would I know?
- If my computer, router, or modem lacks an SPI Bus, how else can we receive the sent bits?

I have searched for examples of SPI Buses on Google with no luck. I have also looked at the Windows Device Manager to see evidence of an SPI bus. Still no dice.

Here is the context of the setup in which we are trying to achieve communication.

```
Single Board Computer with WiFi Module
                |
                |
                |
                |     
     Router, Modem, Other Nexus
                |
                |
                |
                |
     Computer Running Windows 7+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SPI on desktop PC, Modem or router.

Your desktop computer, router or modem is unlikely to have an SPI bus that you can access from an ordinary application on your desktop PC.

You can get USB-attached General-Purpose Input/Output (GPIO) devices that might support this. [Example 1](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9235), [Example 2](http://numato.com/8-channel-usb-gpio-module)

The obvious solution, if you are new to electronics, is to use an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) clone or something similar.

### SPI

SPI is mostly used to communicate between microcontrollers and sensor ICs ([e.g.](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20092a.pdf), [e.g.](http://sensing.honeywell.com/spi%20comms%20with%20digital%20humidity_temp%20sensors%20tn_009071-1-en_final_07jun12.pdf)), other microcontrollers etc. It isn't a natural way to pass data from a Single-Board Computer (SBC) to a Desktop computer, modem or router.

### Communicating between SBC and above devices.

The most obvious methods include

- Serial (nowadays, serial over USB via virtual COM ports)
- Ethernet (SSH, SCP etc or custom TCP or UDP protocols)

Comment: GPIO device means "general purpose input/output device.

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for pointing that out, answer updated to include your clarification.

Comment: In the original question I wrote "we can send bits, one at a time, in sequence, from one place to another". Now, without an SPI Bus on my computer, router, or modem, is there any other way to receive those sent bits?

Comment: The obvious solution that you suggested requires new hardware. I am skeptical that we need more hardware to achieve communication.

Comment: Beautiful edits! It appears that if we want to use serial, we can use USB, but we have the alternative of using Ethernet and TCP or UDP.

Comment: Does "sensor IC" mean sensor integrated circuit?

Comment: @Shaun: [This sort of thing](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20092a.pdf)